# Algorithm for water filling

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

There are some cups of possibly different capacities. Each cup has a label which is a subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. You have a certain amount of water which you can use to fill the cups. At the end, let $x_i$ be the total amount of water in cups with label $i$. You want to maximize $\min(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. How can you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can be reduced to a linear programming problem.

One reference that I found is [this book draft](http://www.4er.org/CourseNotes/Book%20A/A-III.pdf). You can see it at the beginning.

---

More specifically, if the cups have $a_1, \dots, a_m$ water, then every $x_i$ is a linear combination of the $a_j$.

Now we define an extra variable $t$, subject to the constraints $t \leq x_i$ for each $i$. Then the problem becomes to maximize the value of $t$.

---

After the reduction step, you can use any of the usual linear programming algorithms to solve it.

Comment: I see. This would only maximize the minimum, without trying to maximize the second smallest number and so on, right? There may be two solutions with the same minimum, but one solution has much larger other numbers than the other solution.

Comment: Yes, this only maximizes the minimum. But it is already not so simple, thus I don't think it's easy to achieve what you originally want.

Comment: after solving the initlal problem you can fix the water level for the cups that contribute to the minimum, and then create a new optimization problem for the second largest value using the remaining labels. There are probably multiple labels for which the minimum is attained, so you'll end up with a tree of problems. You can also introduce binary variables and optimize it all in a single run.

Comment: Another possibility is to maximize the sum of the $k$ smallest values (which results in a convex problem). The problem with your statement is that there may be many Pareto-optimal solutions, so you need to pick one. (In particular, how large do you want the smallest value, vs. how large do you want the gap between the smallest and next smallest? There's a tradeoff curve between those goals.)

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris My priority is to maximize the minimum first. Then, subject to that, maximize the second smallest number, etc.

Comment: I think this can be reduced to a sequence of convex problems. First, maximize the minimum. Then maximize the sum of the lowest two variables, *subject to* all variables being at least ≥ the minimum found in the previous round. At the k-th round, maximize the sum of the lowest k values, subject to the sum of the 1...k-1 being at least as large as the previous found, giving k-1 additional constraints—one for each of the previously-found values.

It shouldn't be too difficult to show that such a procedure always yields an optimal choice here (in the sense you've described).